# Colour Overlay + Fade

Tags: css, colors, hover, overlay

So I have a tumblr blog and I'd like to set it up so that all the image posts by default have a colour overlayed over the top (almost transparent) and then when you hover over it, it fades out completely to show the image's original colours.

I've been looking for the right code but can't get anything to work. The below code successfully fades out from grayscale, but I don't want grayscale. I'm looking for something that will let me add a solid colour but transparent, and then fade that out. Any ideas? ;A;

(the img is the property used for tumblr images in this CSS code)

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
    
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/285/460/8b6.jpg" width="300px"></img>
```

Comment: FYI you don't need to repeat all of the `transition:` lines for `img:hover` too. `img:hover` will inherit that from `img` so you only need to say it once. Also, `z-index` just uses numbers (you don't need `px`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://jsbin.com/guyudiqafi/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/1200x630/sunrise-sunset-sun-calculator.jpg?1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container:after {
  background: #0043ff;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

.image-container:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want to using `CSS` pseudo-element `:after`.

See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

See working example below:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
.img-wrapper img{
  width: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper:after {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background-color: #ff0000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
}
.img-wrapper.opacity:after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.img-wrapper.rgba:after {
  background-color: rgba(250,0,0,.3);
}
.img-wrapper:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/600x/0b/87/f4/0b87f4eb50b3d7a7c9d70d97234753ab.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-wrapper opacity">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/600x/0b/87/f4/0b87f4eb50b3d7a7c9d70d97234753ab.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-wrapper rgba">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/600x/0b/87/f4/0b87f4eb50b3d7a7c9d70d97234753ab.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: good answer! also, to make the image still be visible through the color overlay, replace `opacity: 1;` with something like `opacity: 0.3;`

Comment: You can also use `background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)` instead change the opacity.